# Unity3D: Build & Run on two Android devices without replugging

Tags: android, build, unity-game-engine, build-process

Is it possible to install a app with one Build & Run process on two connected Android devices?

Or is it possible to have at two devices connected and select the device to build the app without annoying replugging?

Same Question in [UnityAnswers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/366379/build-run-on-two-android-devices-simultaneously.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet possible with Unity, although it is possible on Eclipse. build on one, then select in adb to target another.

In Unity 4 you can choose to build an eclipse project (or you can try the Unity as a subview hack for Unity 3.x, or use appjiggers Unity2Eclipse plugin), from which you can build on two androids from within Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Until we can build and run to multiple devices make a .bat to instruct adb to push the .apk to however many devices you wish.